# How to hide file status [Modified]/[New] in tab name in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

In NetBeans 7 There is a file status after tab's file name ([Modified]/[New]). How can I hide it? Name of a tab already has a different color depending on file's status so there is no need to take that valuable space.

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using (7.0 or 7.1)? What revision control are you using (Git, Mercurial)? I am not seeing the status on the tabs so I'm assuming that my setup is not the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

Goto: `Tools > Miscellanous > Versioning > Subversion`

Set field `format` to {mime_type}

When you clear `format` field completely (or use space character for example), I think NB falls to its default (which is status), that is why I choose {mime_type} property which in my case is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Netbeans 6.0.1 and having the same problem. The versioning labels 'Modified' or 'New' appear at the tab.

So, what you can do is :

go to **View > Untick Show Versioning Labels**

The problem is solved.

Good luck!